# Firefox Add-on: get document from a tab

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, document, firefox-addon-sdk

I was just trying to get the document of a tab and read information from it, but if I try to read the information on the Add-on-side I get an error "doc.getElementById is not a function". In the content-script it works fine. So is there a problem with passing whole objects through self.port?

```
var tabs = require('sdk/tabs');
var myTab;
var myScript = "self.port.on('getDocument', function() {" +
               "  var doc = window.document;" +
               "  console.log(doc.getElementById('lga').style.height);" +
               "  self.port.emit('answer', doc);" +
               "})";

for each (var tab in tabs) {
    if (tab.url == "https://www.google.com/") {
        myTab = tab;
    }
}

worker = myTab.attach({
    contentScript: myScript 
});

worker.port.emit("getDocument");

worker.port.on("answer", function(doc) {
  console.log(doc.getElementById('lga').style.height);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can only pass values via a message that could be serialized to JSON. `doc`, being a document, cannot be passed.

In your message, you could pass the actual value of the style instead:

```
self.port.emit('answer', doc.getElementById('lga').style.height);
```

Comment: Damn. :/ I guess there are no alternative ways to get the whole document?

Comment: No, the intended behaviour is for all interaction with the page to occur within the content script.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than try to import the document into `main.js`, create a new Javascript file in the `data` folder, `ContentScript.js`. Inject it with [**`contentScriptFile`**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/tabs.html#attach%28options%29) into the page like so:

```
worker = myTab.attach({
    contentScriptFile: require('sdk/self').data.url('ContentScript.js')
});
```

Meanwhile, in **ContentScript.js**

```
var doc = window.document;
//Now have your way with the document
```

Then if you ever need any variables in main.js, do what @nmaier said.

I realize that this may be obvious, but this is the intended behaviour, and it means *you don't have to write a script as a string* and provides more detailed logging.